# Perl : how to sum values in a line using PERL

Tags: perl

Perl : how to sum values in a line.

my Data looks like below.

```
"A",1.2,-1.5,4.2,1.4,
"B",2.6,-.50,-1.6,0.3,-1.3
```

Expected Output:

```
5.3
-0.5
```

Comment: More information please.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: i have a file with above sample data... and i need to load the first column to one field.. and the sum of remaining to the next field... hence "A" should be loaded to one field.. and next sum of values to other field...

Comment: Please show us your current code. And explain what problems you are having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 'sum';

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp(my @row = split /,/);
  say sum @row[1 .. $#row];
}

__DATA__
"A",1.2,-1.5,4.2,1.4
"B",2.6,-.50,-1.6,0.3,-1.3
```

(I wouldn't usually give code to answer a question that shows absolutely no effort by the OP. But there's a danger that you'll follow the bad advice in at least one of the other answers.)

**Update:** In the case where you might have extra commas in your data (as in the sample given) then you would need to filter our none-numbers before passing them to `sum()`. The easiest approach is probably to use `looks_like_number()` from the Scalar::Util module.

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';
```

And then, in the `sum()` line...

```
say sum grep { looks_like_number($_) } @row[1 .. $#row];
```

Comment: I like your way better, but bear in mind that the input showed by the OP has a trailing comma in the "A" line that you have omitted. Also, a comment states that the name of each row is also needed (which you have in `$row[0]`).

Comment: Yes. That extra comma throws a warning if you don't remove it. I'd treat that as a reminder to clean up the input. But if you can't do that you'd need to use a `grep` to remove empty fields. The "expected output" in the original question doesn't include the row name - which is why I omitted it.

Comment: @DaveCross.. is there a way to skip the first field ("A") and start calculating from 2nd field?

Comment: @DaveCross.. but I am receiving error.. "Argument "" isn't numeric at subroutine entry"..

Comment: @ricky: That's probably the extra comma that Javier mentioned in his comment above. You'll need to clean up your input data.

Comment: thank you.. for the inputs..:) its working for me..
however would like to remove the last line available at EOF.. 

i tried chomp(my @row = split (',', $input_file, -1); its still reading last line..

Comment: @ricky: If you have a new problem, please ask a new question.

Answer (score -1):

If you're interested in a geeky way of summing, look at this:

```
perl -lpe "()=m{,(?{$_+=$'})}g" in.txt
```

---

```
5.3
-0.5
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'd guess it's because you've posted obscure code without an explanation.

Comment: @DaveCross I think this is one more way to get people interested in Perl. Of course, if OP or some *newbie* asked, I would explain it.